# Randomizing order and spawning of cacti in Trex game

Tags: java, random, processing

I am trying to recreate the Trex game from Chrome. I am using Processing and Java to make this game, but I'm still a beginner in programming (the game is also very crude at this stage). To make my game, I created separate pages for the player, main game, and the various cacti that will appear in the game.

The various cacti in the game are named cactus1, cactus2, and cactus3. The code defining these is quite large, but follow the same structure. The number at the end of the variable shows that cactus it relates to.

My problem is that when I tried to add a randomizer (the commented if statements in the cacti code), the game either doesn't display anything at all or the cacti's height starts freaking out. I tried changing the order of the code as well, but it still does not randomize the spawn or order of the cacti. Please help, thanks in advance! Extra code below:

https://pastebin.com/F4uD1ht3

```
void setup() {
size(1800,1000);
background(255);
}

int gameScore = 0;

void draw() {
  background(255);
  line(0,700,1800,700);//ground
  collision();
  player();
  cactus1();
  if (cactusX <= 0) {//repeat for cactus 1 and add score
      cactusX = 1800;
      cactusHeight = int(random(0,99));
      cactus1();
      gameScore += 1;
    }
  cactus2();
   if (cactusX2 <= 0) {//repeat for cactus 2 and add score
      cactusX2 = 1800;
      cactusHeight2 = int(random(0,99));
      cactus2();
      gameScore += 1;
    }
  cactus3();
  if (cactusX3 <= 0) {//repeat for cactus 3 and add score
      cactusX3 = 1800;
      cactusHeight3 = int(random(0,99));
      cactus3();
      gameScore += 1;
    }
    //println(playerY, cactusX3, cactusHeight3);//diagnosing
}
```

https://pastebin.com/v95e3XNj

```
int cactusWidth = 50;
int cactusX = 800;
int cactusHeight = int(random(0,99));
int randomChance = 0;

void cactus1() {//normal cactus
  //randomChance = int(random(0,100));//uncommenting this will break the game
  //if (randomChance > 50){
    fill(0);
    rect(cactusX, 600 + cactusHeight, cactusWidth, 100 - cactusHeight);
    //}
  for (int count = 0; count <= 1000; count = count + gameSpeed); {
    cactusX = cactusX - gameSpeed;
  }
}

int cactusWidth2 = 75;
int cactusX2 = 1300;
int cactusHeight2 = int(random(0,99));

void cactus2() {//fat cactus
  //randomChance = int(random(0,100));//uncommenting this will break the game
  //if (randomChance > 50){
    fill(0);
    rect(cactusX2, 600 + cactusHeight2, cactusWidth2, 100 - cactusHeight2);
    //}
  for (int count = 0; count <= 1000; count = count + gameSpeed); {
      cactusX2 = cactusX2 - gameSpeed;
  }
}

int cactusWidth3 = 50;
int cactusX3 = 1800;
int cactusHeight3 = int(random(0,99));

void cactus3() {//flying cactus, don't question it
  //randomChance = int(random(0,100));//uncommenting this will break the game
  //if (randomChance > 50){
    fill(0);
    rect(cactusX3, 600, cactusWidth3, 100 - cactusHeight3);
   // }
  for (int count = 0; count <= 1000; count = count + gameSpeed); {
      cactusX3 = cactusX3 - gameSpeed;
  }
}
```

https://pastebin.com/pkHbHutj

```
int playerY = 600;
int playerHeight = 100;
int gameSpeed = 3;

void player() {//player
  fill(0);
  rect(100, playerY, 50, playerHeight);
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'w') {//function for jump
    playerY = 400;
  }
  else if (key == 's') {//function for duck
    playerY = 650;
    playerHeight = 50;
  }
}

void keyReleased() {//also function for jump and duck but the reverse when button is released
  if (key == 'w') {
    playerY = 600;
  }
  else if (key == 's') {
    playerHeight = 100;
    playerY = 600;
  }
}

void collision() { //collision detection, cactus 3 doesn't work when ducking
  if (playerY + playerHeight >= 600 + cactusHeight && 150 >= cactusX && 100 <= cactusX + cactusWidth) {//cactus 1
    gameSpeed = 0;
    println("Your score was " + gameScore + " , Game Over");
  }
  else if (playerY + playerHeight >= 600 + cactusHeight2 && 150 >= cactusX2 && 100 <= cactusX2 + cactusWidth2) {//cactus 2
    gameSpeed = 0;
    println("Your score was " + gameScore + " , Game Over");
  }
  else if (playerY + playerHeight >= 600 && playerY <= 600 + (100 - cactusHeight3) && 150 > cactusX3 && 100 < cactusX3 + cactusWidth3) {//cactus 3
    gameSpeed = 0;
    println("Your score was " + gameScore + " , Game Over");
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Also, please specify which small part of your code fails, what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Peter - the code is included in the labeled pastebins, I could not find a way to attach files, I'm really sorry

Comment: fishinear - if you click the cactus1 image, the commented code (so the randomchance variable and following if statement) breaks the game, I've tried to change the order of code and even where the code is located. Also, just uncommenting the randomchance code for cactus1 seems to break the game, so its obvious that it did not work with all 3 uncommented The pastebin with the cactus code has further information. Thank you for your comment

Comment: In addition, by my understanding the code was basically supposed to have a random chance (set by me), if the variable is in a range (ie the variable randomizes to 50 and the range is x <  75 returning true) it spawns the cactus in and it drags it across the screen (that's the purpose of the for loop if you are following with the code in the pastebin). If the check fails, it runs the cactus1 function again randomizing the number and process repeats

Comment: Peter - alright then, code is pasted

Comment: @fishinear Hello, are you still willing to help? I still have not solved this problem so your help would be quite beneficial.

Apparently you cannot tag more than one person

Comment: It would still be good to give a clear description of what you would expect to happen and what happens in reality. For example, what numbers do you expect the random() calls to return, and what do they return in reality? How often do you expect them to be called, and how often are they called in reality?

Comment: But, for what it is worth, I assume the `cactusHeight`, `cactusHeight2`, and `cactusHeight3` are instance variables. That means they are assigned a value once when the object is created, and keep that value during the lifetime of the object, or until you assign a new value to them. Is that what you expect to happen, and is that what really happens?

Comment: @fishinear when I call random randomChance I'm basically telling the computer to pick a random number from 0 to 100. If this number is greater than 50, the code should run. I tried fiddling around with the code a bit more yesterday, and I discovered that the reason my code wasn't working is because the random chance variable was deciding whether the cactus was visible or not. In processing, the draw function runs 60 times a second so I figured out that I should probably not place the randomChance in the cactus1 function. Along with this, random chance is shared by all 3 cacti so I think(1/2)

Comment: It would be better to have different variables for the different cacti? Also I now realized I need help with making a randomizer for the different functions. Do you have a way to randomly call different functions? This can help by calling cactus1 then somehow running 2 different instances of the same function which I don't know how to do (2/2)

Comment: What would be normal to do, is to have one `cactusHeight` instance variable, and one `draw` method that draws the cactus based on the value of its `cactusHeight` (instead of the three `cactus` methods that you have). The constructor method would then set the value of `cactusHeight` (randomly or however you want to do that). Then you create a different cactus object for each cactus in the game.

Comment: Just realised that might not be clear to a new programmer. What I meant is that you create a Cactus class that incorporates all aspects of what it means to be a cactus. One aspect of a cactus is its height, so that would be an instance variable of the Cactus class. Similarly, a Person class would represent the person in your game, and a Game class represents the game itself. The Game class would then create one new Person object, and a number of new Cactus objects.

Comment: @fishinear yeah I tried to wrap my head around it and I'm stumped. What would I tell the computer if I want it to create a new class? Does this mean I have to trash all my cacti functions? I also don't think I have a game class, its just a void draw (if you use processing). I'm really sorry, I'm still really new to programming

Comment: Or do each of the pages in processing mean a new class, because I have separate pages for the 3 things. Could you perhaps provide example code if it doesn't trouble you too much? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, so I recommend that you read a good Object Oriented programming book or online tutorial to get started.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @fishinear: You should write your comments as an answer.

Comment: @PeterO. Well, they are not really an answer to their main question, as to why the randomising in their game does not work, so I thought it would not be appropriate to write them as answer.